# Find average value from a column of stream dataframe with array values using spark scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

I have the following stream dataframe

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|______name__________________|______orderOfHobbies_____________________|
| Liza                       |   [singing, painting]                   |
| Inter                      |   [singing, singing]                    |
| Ovin                       |   [singing, playing, reading, singing]  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to find the favorite hobby of each student. If the occurrence of each hobby per each student is equal then I want to drop the record. eg- Liza's record will be dropped. Since singing is frequently occurred with Inter and Ovin singing will be the favorite hobby.

Expected output

```
+----------------------------------------------------
|______name__________________|______favoriteHobby___|                  
| Inter                      |   singing            |
| Ovin                       |   singing            |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a UDF:

```
val favoriteUDF = udf(
    (hobby: Seq[String]) => 
    if ((hobby.distinct.size != hobby.size) || (hobby.size == 1)) 
    hobby.groupBy(identity).maxBy(_._2.size)._1 
    else "invalid"
)

val df2 = df.select(
    col("name"), 
    favoriteUDF(col("orderOfHobbies")).as("favoriteHobby")
).filter("favoriteHobby != 'invalid'")

df2.show
+-----+-------------+
| name|favoriteHobby|
+-----+-------------+
|Inter|      singing|
| Ovin|      singing|
+-----+-------------+
```

Comment: after removing the else part of the udf im getting the following error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Any is not supported. how can i get rid of this?

Comment: You must specify `else` to make the return type unambiguous. Why do you want to remove that part?

Comment: because with null from else part  i got unsafe exception

Comment: ok, then you can return `"invalid"` instead. See edited answer. @tharindu